# Get last major published version of items returned as DataRow (from SPSiteDataQuery)

Tags: splistitem, versioning, version-history, spsitedataquery

Does anyone know the solution for this?

If I'm querying items by SPSiteDataQuery I receive a DataTable with DataRow objects.

I could fetch the current version of an item and check if it ends with ".0" (indicating a major version).

If it **isn't a major version**, I could convert the 
DataRow to SPListItem and get the last published major version as SPListItem.

Else (if it **is a major version**) i can proceed with my DataRow object:

```
DataTable results = ...//get results from SPSiteDataQuery

foreach (DataRow row in results.Rows){

 string version = (string)row["_UIVersionString"];

 if (!version.EndsWith("0"))
 {
    string absUrl = (string)row["EncodedAbsUrl"];
    SPListItem item = web.GetFile(absUrl).Item;
    SPListItem newestItem = null;

    foreach (SPListItem publishedMajorVersionItem in item.Versions)
    {
      if (publishedMajorVersionItem.Level == SPFileLevel.Published)
        newestItem = publishedMajorVersionItem;
    }
 }

 //proceed with DataRow object
 CustomObject o = new CustomObject();
 o.Title = (string)row["Title"];
}
```

**What is missing is:** how can I get a DataRow object from the SPListItem?

**Or:** is there  another way to get the last major published version if I'm using SPSiteDataQuery without converting the DataRow to SPListItem?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot, but since you already have your item in hand you can update your current row with latest item data. Something like:

```
foreach (DataColumn column in results.Columns)
{
    SPField field = newestItem.Fields.TryGetFieldByStaticName(column.ColumnName);
    if (field != null)
    {
        row[field.InternalName] = newestItem[field.InternalName];
    }
 }
 row.AcceptChanges();
```

Please note I didn't test this code. I am just providing it as example.